How to implement MSAL popup Login Mode for Blazor Server?
I want to implement MSAL popup login mode for Blazor Server, but still fail to do so.
Only found a way to use popup login mode for Blazor WebAssembly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-entra-id?view=aspnetcore-8.0
For Blazor WebAssembly is just a simple configuration in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // ...
            options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect"; //can choose redirect or popup
        });

But for Blazor Server, I still cannot find it.
It is the requirement for me to implement the popup login instead of redirect login.
Your help/view really appreciated
I need to be able to login by using popup login mode instead of redirect.

You could try following sample works for .NET 7 "blazor server app" with "Microsoft Identity Platfrom" template.

After create the project, Add a auth.js to wwwroot folder.

function openPopup(url, name, width, height) {
    const left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    const top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    return window.open(url, name, `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`);
}

function authenticateUser() {
    const Url = '/authentication/login'; 
    const popup = openPopup(Url, 'loginPopup', 600, 600);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (popup.closed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function logoutUser() {
    const Url = '/authentication/logout';
    const popup = openPopup(Url, 'logoutPopup', 600, 600);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (popup.closed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, 1000);
}


In _Host.cshtml add the script reference

...
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="./auth.js"></script>
</body>


Under "Pages" folder, add a razor page named Close.cshtml and add windows.close for close close popup purpose.

@page
<script>
    window.close();
</script>


In the project root create a "Controllers" folder. Add a  AuthenticationController to handle the scheme login/logout.

    [Route("authentication")]
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            // Generate the URL to initiate login
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("LoginCallback", "Authentication")
            };
            return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        [Route("LoginCallback")]
        public IActionResult LoginCallback()
        {
            // to close pop up , need to redirect to a page which can use javascript
            return Redirect("/close");
        }

        [Route("logout")]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

    }


Modify the Shared/LoginDisplay.razor like following to call js when click login/logout button:

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <a href="" onclick="logoutUser()">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="" onclick="authenticateUser()">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


Remove the global authorization policy in program.cs. Unfortnately, this sample only support popup when click a login button. Not for scheme challenge directly.

//builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//{
//    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
//    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
//});


Make sure you add the redirect url to spa platform in EntraId App and have domain/cliendId/TenantId in appsettings.



@hafizsz Glad to hear that. Would you help to follow the instruction:) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.
